# TransactionScope: is there a risk of ghost transactions with distributed transactions when a crash is occuring?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, .net-core, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I'm using distributed transactions with the `TransactionScope` class with SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

I have some concerns about potential crashes and if that occurs while committing the whole distributed transaction, I'm wondering if there are potentially prepared transactions left behind and stuck in regard to PostgreSQL or SQL Server? If that's the case, how to avoid that?

[EDIT 1]

I also strongly recommend reading the comments below that [article](https://ayende.com/blog/167362/the-fallacy-of-distributed-transactions).

I quote:

> [...] What if it is an Oracle db running on Linux? Or a RavenDB running on the cloud? In both cases, a proxy has to be used.
>
> [...] You have to go and manually resolve those issues, because as a result of this issue, you have permanently locked transactions.

[EDIT 2]
Adding a bit more info the [`TransactionScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for SQL Server, but in Postgres, yes this can happen.

In theory it's the responsibility of the transaction manager (the software that controls the distributed transaction) to clean them up.

If the transaction manager doesn't clean up properly (e.g. after a crash) then you need to do that manually.

You can use the system view [pg_prepared_xacts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-prepared-xacts.html) to monitor the "prepared transactions".

You could query that view and check the age of the transactions. If that age exceeds some threshold (suitable for your environment) then you can terminated them manually using [`rollback prepared`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-rollback-prepared.html)

Comment: The Transaction Manager you mentioned, in my scenario is a job supposedly filled by the `TransactionScope` class.

Comment: That being said, is there like a timeout / expiration date for orphan transactions, so that PostgreSQL can do the garbage collection on its own?

Comment: @KerryPerret: a transaction manager is a service that manages the distributed transactions and coordinates all external sources. This is typically provided by an application server.

Comment: @KerryPerret: no there is no timeout. This has recently been discussed [on the hackers mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CANugjhsnEt2qmhRh7zpNYUbhjsEyorb-pX-eb1fD4K9qeTybbQ%40mail.gmail.com) with the consent that Postgres shouldn't clean up the mess the XA manager leaves behind. And doing that would actually break the contract of the 2-phase-commit protocol for distributed transactions

Comment: alright thanks, kinda makes sense from the "DB perspective"

Comment: and ooc, there is no other way around to achieve distributed transactions without taking the risks of having orphans, right?

Comment: @KerryPerret: the risk of orphaned transactions is determined by the stability and robustness of your XA manager

Comment: Crystal clear, thanks, will probably go for an expiration time window strategy then (or whatever works best for me)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible - but it is EXTREMELY unlikely as open transactions will be rolled back.

System.Transaction relies on the windows integrated transaction broker which implements 3 phase commit. Your system must crash in a VERY specific moment for problems (which result in a broken transaciotn that can be rolled back manually in the tx manager ui). AND use MORE THAN ONE RESSOURCE (i.e. 2 db connections) otherwise it just wraps a local one ressource transaction.

There is a reason some systems use 5 phase commit protocols (so there is a chance of something going bad) but it already is VERY relaible. Note that tx's are written to a persistent log UNLESS you talk of only one transaction ressource.